# TableView separator disappear

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I select rows from top to bottom, separator appears. However when I scroll the rows, the separator removed.

When I select rows from bottom to top, separator doesn't appear.

How can I keep the separator always existed?

I have searched for a while and seems there is no solution yet.

Comment: Are you adding custom separators? or did you check if anywhere you wrote self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None

Comment: No, i didn't do that. By default it won't show up the separator. will it?

Comment: Yes UITableView default property is to show the separator. Can you share a screenshot of the storyboard, where you have added the UITableView

Comment: yes, i know uitableview default property is to show the separator. would it still show up after i selected some rows?

Comment: @henry, Set the default separator to nil. Create a custom `UIView` with height 1px and set it to the bottom of cell's `content view`.

Answer (score 0):

When you simply add a UITableView, it shows the separator like these. The separator remains there when you select, reload or perform any other function.

Other can be check if the separator is selected to default or none.

[image: UITableView]

[image: Separator]

[image: Cell selection]

At one time you can select single row only. The selection color being same as the separator. It appears there is no separator. Plus when you have multi select. Its default functionality that it appears that there is no separator.

[image: Multi]

Comment: Could you show the screen for selecting two consecutive rows? thank you.

Comment: Sure, just a minute

Comment: You can select multiple selection in storyboard. Also, it is not the matter of separator colour. you can change the colour of it and try again.

Comment: Updated that above. So i also suppose its default functionality. You don't need to worry.

Comment: i am looking for the answer of showing the separator. i can't see there is any solution now.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a cell for each table view row
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellReuseIdentifier) as UITableViewCell!

        // set the text from the data model
        cell.textLabel?.text = mainArr[indexPath.row]
       //Main item here is set selection style none.
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        return cell
    }
```

and when you select a row, add a new UIView or ImageView to the cell which is same width as cell view but height should be cell.height-1

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        var customView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, (cell?.frame.width)!, 43))
        customView.backgroundColor = .redColor()
        customView.alpha=0.3
        cell!.addSubview(customView)
    }
```

In this manage an algorithm, that way you can come to know if the row has to be selected or deselected and that way add the view or remove the view from the cell.